# This tag is a [flash] in the pan

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

For a long time now I've been watching the [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) tag. On the wiki it's supposed to be for questions regarding Adobe Flash, but a large proportion of the questions posted are about Flash Memory, Camera Flash, Flash Messages, or Flask (presumably people type "flas" and click the first suggestion without reading it)

I've racked up a lot of rep points from just editing these mis-tags. Ideally there would only be an explicit [adobe-flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash) tag instead of such an ambiguous [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash).

Comment: The [tag:adobe-flash] exist, but for some reason is synonymized to plain [tag:flash]

Comment: Especially with adobe flash being flattened, this is a good idea.

Comment: Let's flush the [tag:flash]

Comment: We should deal with this tag in a [tag:flash].

Answer (score 11):

The natural way to solve this would be to burninate [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) - it is a strong candidate for sure. Then re-tagging posts to either [adobe-flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash) and [flash-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-memory). These would be the two major topics, although other "flashy things" seem to exist as well. All flash memory questions should probably be tagged with [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded).

Given that there's 35k questions to deal with, this would however require quite some effort.

Comment: You mean you don't have a USB flash drive yet?

Comment: I'd save the burninating for *after* the retagging is done.

Comment: @Joshua Why would I find myself programming that one? And it's called flash drive because it has flash memory.

Comment: @BoltClock Not sure what you mean. Retagging means going through all them posts and give them the correct tag. Once that's done, there will be no more posts tagged flash and the burnination is done. But it is 35k questions, so...

Comment: Once you've burninated the tag it'll become much more difficult to find those 35k questions again to retag unless you have good search coverage. You don't need to retag all 35k questions, just possibly the mistagged ones and possibly a tag rename or something. The overwhelming majority of these questions are about Adobe Flash anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah yeah, automatic removal isn't gonna work, agree.

Comment: I was under the impression that burnination just meant "we don't want this tag in any of the questions" not that for that to be achieved we needed an automated process (ie. Shogs pawa).